# adding android fragment in tabhost

Tags: android, fragment

I have a view pager which hosts 4 fragments: this is the xml of the viewPagerActivity

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/tabviewpager"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Now in one of the fragments I have a Listview.In its onListItemClick function i've written the code above so that every time an item on the list gets clicked,a fragment would appear providing some extra information.I've done it in a demo(where I only had a LinearLayout and I would add it there ).But i can't do it in my application.

```
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    int MARGIN = 16;

    ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    RightFragment rightFragment =  new RightFragment(getResources().getColor(
            R.color.honeycombish_blue), 2f, MARGIN / 2, MARGIN, MARGIN,
            MARGIN);

    ft.add(R.id.,rightFragment );

    ft.commit();

}
```

and that is my fragment class:

```
public class RightFragment extends SherlockFragment {

private View mView;
private int mColour;
private float mWeight;
private int marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop, marginBottom;

// need a public empty constructor for framework to instantiate
public RightFragment() {

}

public RightFragment(int colour, float weight, int margin_left,
        int margin_right, int margin_top, int margin_bottom) {
    mColour = colour;
    mWeight = weight;
    marginLeft = margin_left;
    marginRight = margin_right;
    marginTop = margin_top;
    marginBottom = margin_bottom;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    mView = new View(getActivity());


    GradientDrawable background = (GradientDrawable) getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_rect);
    background.setColor(mColour);

    mView.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, mWeight);
    lp.setMargins(marginLeft, marginTop, marginRight, marginBottom);
    mView.setLayoutParams(lp);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    System.out.println("'");
  mView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfrg, container, false);


  GradientDrawable background = (GradientDrawable) getResources()
          .getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_rect);
  background.setColor(mColour);

  mView.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, mWeight);
  lp.setMargins(marginLeft, marginTop, marginRight, marginBottom);
  mView.setLayoutParams(lp);

  return mView;
}

}
```

!which layout should i use as the root for my new fragment.Hope the picture helps[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuORc.png)